# Get info from a form when submitting one in a page with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML page with multiple forms. The code looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    Hour: <select name="hour_id">...</select>
    Class: <select name="class_id">...</select>
    Teacher: <select name="teacher_id">...</select>
    <a class="go_to_class">Go to class</a>
</form>

<form method="post" action="#">
    Hour: <select name="hour_id">...</select>
    Class: <select name="class_id">...</select>
    Teacher: <select name="teacher_id">...</select>
    <a class="go_to_class">Go to class</a>
</form>

<form method="post" action="#">
    Hour: <select name="hour_id">...</select>
    Class: <select name="class_id">...</select>
    Teacher: <select name="teacher_id">...</select>
    <a class="go_to_class">Go to class</a>
</form>

[...]

<form method="post" action="#">
    Hour: <select name="hour_id">...</select>
    Class: <select name="class_id">...</select>
    Teacher: <select name="teacher_id">...</select>
    <a class="go_to_class">Go to class</a>
</form>
```

What I would like to do is to write a jQuery code to allow me to submit any form and send those informations via POST to an AJAX script. Also, I need to perform a little validation to make sure that the user has selected a value for "hour", "class" and "teacher" in the form he wants to submit.

In terms of jQuery, I know how to serialize form values and to send them to the script, but I don't know how to get the values in order to perform validation.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.go_to_class').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('form').submit(function() {
            var values = $(this).serialize();
        });
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: For a start go_to_class is a CLASS and you refer to it as a ID. Try changing `$('#go_to_class').click(function(e) {` to this `$('.go_to_class').click(function(e) {`

Comment: Typo. I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .serializeArray() to get all the input fields

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('.go_to_class').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
    });

    $('form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var fields = $( this ).serializeArray();
        $.each(fields, function(i,field){
            console.log(field.name,field.value);
        });
    });

});
```